# Commincation Help

Tags: ros, communication

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a question. I am new to ROS and was wondering about communicating with other packages. I am running low level control on a rasperry pi and want to publish data to another computer that is running ROS. Is there any way I can do that without having to put ROS on my raspberry pi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254613/commincation-help/) by [Andres45](https://answers.ros.org/users/29353/andres45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there any way I can do that without having to put ROS on my raspberry pi

Yes, one option could be [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andres45](https://answers.ros.org/users/29353/andres45/) on 2017-02-14**:
Appreciate it I will look into it